# Accessing data via LinkedIn APIs

Tags: linkedin-api

We need to use LinkedIn for both or either of the following:

1. Pull-out user information e.g. Employers, Years worked with a
   particular employer, Education etc. from LinkedIn Profile
2. When a user provide us data about their Employers, Years worked
   with, Education etc. we can validate it with their LinkedIn Profile.

I want to know if it's possible.

Comment: Its possible but will not be reliable. See my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118433/636799