# Linkedin inbox API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I tried to search a lot but seems like what i am trying to do has not been done before. Here is what I am trying. I am trying to figure out a way to make a script that takes a linkedin profile url as input and checks if I have sent  any message to that profile in past. If I have sent script gives me "true" if no message in past has been sent to that script gives me "false". I tried to search linkedin API for same but I could not find any help on that. Any opinion from all your experts out there please? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly you are asking.

But the Linkedin API is terrible and should be avoided, they have a track record of screwing over 3rd party apps.  AFAIK you cannot get any data about a user except their basic profile info and even that is unpredictable, sometimes you'll get like 4 fields at most. Don't let this page fool you: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

If you want you can try your luck and apply for their 'partner' program or as i like to call it: lets-see-if-we-can-steal-your-idea-before-you-get-big-enough-that-we-are-forced-to-compete/acquire-you